# what loop condition can be used to make the code run continuously

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple code for the copying the cell value. How to make it run in a loop

```
Selection.FillDown
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is not clear. Would you like to explain a bit what you want to achieve? For your info, using `.Select` is not a recommended way in most cases.

Comment: What is selected? Loop over all rows? Loop over all columns? Loop over all sheets? This question needs much clarification.

Comment: By using the code i m copying the value present in A522 to A523 and then moving down to next blank cell i.e A527.   I need this to be continued until data present in the last column. I have attached the sample data in image format

Comment: `While` `For` a Loop you could `Do` many things, the solution to `GoTo` will change depending on exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I do not recommend a infinite loop, so define max row number, or looping from a selection should be good.

```
for each cel in Selection
   if cel.value="" then
      cel.value=cel.offset(-1,0).value
   end if
next
```

should loop through the cells you have selected filling out the blank ones from the data of upper cell.

Comment: This is not doing the same what i asked for.

Comment: Have you selected all the cells where you want to apply it? or is it not doing correct operation?

Comment: I have selected by it is showing the code has error in below part   "cel.value=cel.offset(0,-1).value"

Comment: you could tell what does the error says. I don't have excel right now to try so. Don't select the cells on the first row, the offset(0,-1) is not available for the first row.

Comment: Yup It worked Now  by changing the offset value to (-1,0). Thanks for the timely response

Comment: oh yeah, sorry for meshing up, i'll correct that. I would have known that if i had excel to try on. I am using linux and miss VBA.